# play mp3 file with MPMoviePlayer in background

Tags: iphone, xcode, audio, mpmovieplayercontroller, mpmovieplayer

I am using this `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to play `.mp3` file from server but not working properly.
Here is the code i am using.

```
NSString *path = @"http://myurl/music.mp3";
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mpviewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
mpviewController.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;  
[self presentModalViewController:mpviewController animated:YES];
[[mpviewController moviePlayer] play];
```

Audio play for 3 or 5 seconds only then it stops automatically. Cant figure out whats the problem. 
Your suggestions would be great help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by this code :)
May it helps someone.

```
NSString *path = @"http://myurl/mymusic.mp3";
mv = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:path]];
mv.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeUnknown;
[self.view addSubview:mv.view];
[mv play];
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using this [GIT](https://github.com/mattgallagher/AudioStreamer) for audio streaming from my server. it is simple to use repo.

At the time I have imported to my project it didn't have any background playing. I have added that with some simple iOS code.

Answer (score 0):

### Maybe you should retain your mpviewController,  I make the same misstake.